# SwiftUI - Changing GraphicalDatePickerStyle DatePicker's visibility causes memory leak

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, datepicker, swiftui

I have an app that has a datepicker (`GraphicalDatePickerStyle`). It hidden by default. When you tap the view that contains it, it becomes visible.

**DateTimePicker**

```
struct DateTimePicker<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding var selection: Date
    
    @State private var isDatePickerVisible: Bool = false
        
    private var displayedComponents: DatePickerComponents
    
    private var content: (_ isVisible: Bool) -> Content
    
    
    init(selection: Binding<Date>,
         displayedComponents: DatePickerComponents = [.date],
         content: @escaping (_ isVisible: Bool) -> Content) {
        self._selection = selection
        self.content = content
        self.displayedComponents = displayedComponents
    }
    

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            self.content(isDatePickerVisible)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.isDatePickerVisible.toggle()
                    }
                }
            if isDatePickerVisible {
                VStack {
                    DatePicker("",
                               selection: $selection,
                               displayedComponents: self.displayedComponents)
                        .labelsHidden()
                        .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView that contains DateTimePicker**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var selection = Date()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            DateTimePicker(selection: $selection) { _ in
                HStack {
                    Text("Date ")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(selection)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are a few memory leaks if you show and hide `DateTimePicker`.  I tried a lot but could not fix it.

[image]